# Eclipse + PDT performance tips?

Tags: php, eclipse, performance, eclipse-pdt

I recently wanted to get a decend IDE for my PHP side-projecs, and by searching SO found Eclipse+PDT. Although it's not quite at the level of Visual Studio yet, it's pretty nice and better than Notepad++ for this purpose. I can even debug somewhat, although it's pretty glitchy.

But there is one thing that is bugging me. It seems to have some kind of weird performance issue, whereupon it it uses lots of CPU about once a minute or so. By itself this is not noticeable, but if you do something else at the same time (like watch a movie, or play Quake 3), it produces an annoying hicup now and then.

Granted, my computer is not state-of-the-art (Sempron 2200+ with 1GB of RAM), but then it's certainly more than enough for all of this.

Another performance question is that I'm used to Visual Studio where IntelliSense pops up as soon as you type a compatible symbol. Here you have to wait for a moment. Is there any way to make it open up instantly?

P.S. Perhaps there's an even better **freeware** IDE for PHP?

**Added:** It was suggested by Stefan Schmidt to change Auto-Activation speed. It seems that there is a bug with this. The smaller I set it, the more it fails to open at all. For example, when it's 200, it opens mostly all the time when there is something to open. At 10 it doesn't open (at least) for static class members. What gives?

Comment: The same here with a much beefier config (dual Core2 duo with 4G or RAM) using Eclipse 3.4

Answer (score 2):

I *think* I found it !!!

Given:

a) That Eclipse for PHP (Eclipse PDT) is updated just about everyday complete with daily builds. I can only assume this is from a team of very dedicated and competent developers who only want the same thing you do.

b) That only a small portion of us have been coming here complaining about our CPU maxing out while trying to edit PHP code.

Observations:

a) I have turned off just about every item in the preferences box to no avail.

Solutions:

In my past experience with software, especially large black boxes that normally work well for others. When faced with a situation that does not seem to respond to conventional theory... I like to do the unconventional. In this case... simply take care of the "little things".

In this particular case this means that I:

1. Did an update via Help->Check for Software Updates
2. Installed the latest updates
3. Removed the old workspace and created a new one
4. Paid attention to ALL THE WARNINGS, especially the YELLOW warnings which kept pointing to all the HTML errors in code that I either wasn't really using or meant to clean up anyway.

In other words...

Once I eliminated ALL THE WARNINGS.... The CPU stopped maxing out !!!

After updating the to latest Eclipse build and then taking the time to either fix the warnings and/or remove ALL unnecessary source code (that was slated to removed anyway)... the CPU returned to "normal".

In other words...

The problem was not that Eclipse PDT wasn't working properly...

...it was that it was working TOO GOOD !!!

It was doing precisely what it was designed to do... check ( & recheck ) for warnings in your source code while the keyboard was considered dormant.

So...

There you go...

Pay attention to ALL the warnings in your "Problems" window and do what it takes to reduce the number of warnings to ZERO !!!

And then report back here with your findings.

I honestly cannot believe just how well my Ubuntu 10.04 (32 bit) installation is operating on a $500 Compaq Presario. It's a dream and ALL I did was take care of the "little things".

Cheers,

Perry

Comment: Interesting. :) Although a little too late for me, I'm afraid. :P I already switched to Netbeans ages ago, and then again to simply Notepad++. And I also upgraded my PC. So... let's hope someone else finds this useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be the garbage collector. Try a different JVM or a different garbage collection algorithm. It might help you shorten the pause times. With [JRockit](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/jrockit/index.html) you can set a pause time target for the garbage collector.

For instance you could set:

```
-XgcPrio:pausetime 
-XpauseTarget:250
```

in you eclipse.ini file. See this [blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/hirt/2008/08/running_eclipseworkshop_on_jro.html) for some information on how you can set up Eclipse to run on JRockit

Comment: I had this too with older versions of Java (even the 1.6 series). Try updating to the latest one and perhaps tuning the -X parameters as Kire suggests.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

Selec Project => clean from menu and select all php projects. This could take a while ( if you have many/large projects ), but then it should get faster.

For an alternate free IDE you could try [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/php/index.html). From version 6.5 it has full php support, and for me it's faster than Eclipse+PDT, and more stable / memory consupting.

Answer (score 1):

There are known issues with PDT 3.1 and eclipse 4.2 (juno).

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272

This is the solution:

Open a different perspective (for example java, but not php) and restart eclipse. Afterwards you can savely switch back to php perspective. Eclipse will have no performance issues.

Also mentioned [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation_3.1.x)

Comment: You shouldn't post the same message over each question related to Eclipse PDT. You should post an answer and then link to it.

Comment: Also it is probably not a eclipse 4.2 issue since this question was asked 3 years ago :p

Answer (score 0):

For your second question:

- Go to Window->Preferences ...
- From there go to PHP->Editor->Code Assist
- At the bottom is a box called Auto-Activation.

There you can specify the delay it takes for the Code Assist to show up.

I have no solution for your other problem, but perhaps if you wait until 29th of December your problems will be solved by the 2.0 version.

Edit: Not a solution, but perhaps a workaround: Try lowering the prcess priority of your PDT process.

Comment: Hmm... aparently there is a bug with this. Check question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas then. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ive had no hiccups using PDT with Ganymede .. you might want to try (as an experiment) downloading and copying eclipse from the [All-in-One Eclipse PDT + Zend Debugger Package](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt) zip and see if it runs better?

You can use multiple different eclipses as they don't need any installation and won't interfere with each other - just open and use

Answer (score 0):

There is another project for adding PHP support to Eclipse: [PHPeclipse](http://www.phpeclipse.com/). I know that when PDT was still young, people often choose PHPeclipse because of performance problems with PDT, but I cannot say, how the current versions of both compare with respect to performance (and features), as I quit my PHPeclipse development activities quite some time ago.

If your performance problem is a real show stopper, you might want to give PHPeclipse a try.